# Undefined result after passing to the next screen using random function

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having trouble on a undefined value I get after passing from one screen (Home) to another screen (SubScreen2) after randomizing the value in a drop down picker

Home

```
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
             {label: 'Fast Food', value: 'Fast Food'},                  
             {label: 'Western', value: 'Western'},
             {label:'Beverage', value:'Berverage'},
             {label:'Chinese', value:'Chinese'},
             {label: 'Korean', value: 'Korean'},
             {label: 'Taiwanese', value: 'Taiwanese'},                  
             {label: 'Malay', value: 'Malay'},
             {label: 'Indonesian', value: 'Indonesian'},
             {label: 'Indian', value: 'Indian'},                  
             {label: 'Vietnamese', value: 'Vietnamese'},
             {label: 'Japanese', value: 'Japanese'},
             {label: 'Italian', value: 'Italian'},
             {label: 'Desserts', value: 'Desserts'},
             {label: 'Others', value: 'Others'},
            ]);
  const handleSignOut = async () =>{
    try{
      await signOut(auth)
      console.log("Signed out successfully")
      navigation.replace("Login")
    }catch (error) {
      console.log({error});
   }
   
  }
  const setRandomValue = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    const randomValue = setValue([items[randomIndex].label.toLowerCase()]);
    console.log(randomIndex)
    console.log(randomValue)
    navigation.navigate("SubScreen2", {paramKey:randomValue})
  }
  
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <Text>Welcome {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
      <Text></Text>
      <Text>What cusine would you like to eat today?</Text>
      <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
    />
    
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SubScreen1", {paramKey:value})}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Search</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={setRandomValue}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Random</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleSignOut}
        style = {styles.button}
      >
        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Sign Out</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

SubScreen2

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const SubScreen2 = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey
  console.log(paramKey)
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{paramKey}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen2

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Under the function of `setRandomValue` in my Home, I have 2 variables which are `randomIndex` and `randomValue`. I can get a numeric output from `randomIndex` but a *undefined* output from `randomValue`. From here I pass the value to the next page  (SubScreen2) via `paramKey`. The output I get is undefined here as in the previous page the output was undefined. So here is the question, what am I doing something wrong here? I am trying to randomize the value and move it to the next page so then I can continue using the value and search thru firebase database to extract the data I need. Example, Lets say the computer decides to pick `Japanese`, this `Japanese` will be passed to the 2nd page (SubScreen2) and within SubScreen2, `Japanese` will be used to search thru the firebase database to extract `Japanese` related and display on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning the `setValue` setState function to the `randomValue` instead of the actual value.

```js
const setRandomValue = () => {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
  const randomValue = items[randomIndex].label.toLowerCase(); // only assigning the label
  setValue(randomValue);
  console.log(randomIndex);
  console.log(randomValue);
  navigation.navigate("SubScreen2", { paramKey: randomValue });
};
```

Comment: No wonder. Thanks ! It work perfectly now